# Error when doing mail merge - MS Access Cannot find the file mdb

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a query I am trying to do a mail merge on; the query runs great but when I try to do a Mail Merge in Access 2007 I get the following Error Message in a pop-up window:

```
Pop-up title:  ODBC Microsoft Access Driver Login Failed
Error Message: Could not find file: 'D:\folder\myfile.mdb
```

I am not sure where this file is or why this is happening.

Thanks everyone!

Guy

Comment: Are you attaching from Word to MS Access? As an aside, I decided a good few years ago that life was a lot easier with a text file outout from MS Access for all interaction with Word Mailmerge.

Comment: Yes I am using a MS 2007 Word Document.

Comment: Perhaps: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318532 I strongly suggest you use text output as your merge file.

Comment: I am not understanding when you say use text output. I am trying to perform the mail merge using the query result-set. Thank you!

Comment: Save the query result as text and use that for the mailmerge. You can use DoCmd.Transfertext to create the text file.

Comment: Thank you, I also just used an Excel but your suggestion also works.
Thanks again!